# How to create a column in a table constrained by a foreign key OR an custom default value?

Tags: postgresql

So, I have the following DB:

[image]

List of users.
Each user can add domains.
Each user can add links. The link has a `domainId` column that is limited to values from the `Domain` table. However, this column must also accept one pre-defined value - "example.com" as the default value. **Therefore, the `domainId` column must be limited to values from the `Domain` table or to the value "example.com".** How to do it?

My initialization:

```sql
-- CreateTable
CREATE TABLE "User"
(
    "id" SERIAL NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT "User_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);

-- CreateTable
CREATE TABLE "Link"
(
    "id"       SERIAL  NOT NULL,
    "ownerId"  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "domainId" TEXT    NOT NULL DEFAULT 'example.com',

    CONSTRAINT "Link_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);

-- CreateTable
CREATE TABLE "Domain"
(
    "id"      TEXT,
    "ownerId" INTEGER NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT "Domain_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);

-- AddForeignKey
ALTER TABLE "Link"
    ADD CONSTRAINT "Link_ownerId_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("ownerId") REFERENCES "User" ("id") ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

-- AddForeignKey
ALTER TABLE "Link"
    ADD CONSTRAINT "Link_domainId_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("domainId") REFERENCES "Domain" ("id") ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE;

-- AddForeignKey
ALTER TABLE "Domain"
    ADD CONSTRAINT "Domain_ownerId_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("ownerId") REFERENCES "User" ("id") ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

With this initialization, I get an error (which is logical) that the "example.com" does not satisfy the foreign key constraint

Comment: The value of a FK column **must** exist as a value in the referenced column. So if  `example.com` is to be the default value the table `link` then  the  `domain` table must contain a row with `example.com` as the id.

Comment: A potential alternative is let `link.domain` be null-able and null by default. Then create a view which used `coalesce(domain,'example.com')`. In your code use this view instead of the actual table.